# Dump MySql Db by daterange

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a large database, and I want to dump the data after custom day, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mysqldump **where**

or try to export schema and data seperately for each table with below command

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --tab=/tmp dbname
```

you will have one tablename.sql file containing each table's schema (create table statement) and tablename.txt file containing the data in /tmp directory.

if you want a dump with schema only, add the --no-data flag:

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --no-data --tab=/tmp dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a "[**where**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)" condition .

Dumps only rows selected by the given WHERE condition.